# How to resolve URI parameters in string URL through java/spring code?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have url like `http://www.example.com/api/{uriparam}/something`

How should I replace the `uriparam` with my parameter call `test`? 
So that it will be like `http://www.example.com/api/test/something`

Answer (score 0):

In rest API its called as path, to do that, here is sample of controller using path. here is sample with jax rs.

```
@Path("/testUrl/{data}")
@GET
public String checkPending(@PathParam("data") String data) {
    String yourUrl = "http://www.example.com/api/" + data + "/something";
    return yourUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder as below :-

```
Map<String, String> parameters  = new java.util.HashMap<String,String>();
parameters.put("uriparam","test");

String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://www.example.com/api/{uriparam}/something".trim()).buildAndExpand(parameters).encode().toString();
```

it will return you the required url